# new tumblr account restrictions - what is required to unlock features?

Tags: tumblr

i'm developing a tumblr theme that hinges a lot on the user being able to add redirect pages, but when you create a new tumblr account that option is unavailable at first.  the only official word on this that i can get is:

> "In order to prevent spam and other types of abuse on Tumblr, that
>   feature is locked on new accounts. After you’ve used the account for
>   awhile to do things like following other blogs and choosing your
>   blog’s appearance, the feature will be unlocked so you can use it. We
>   apologize for the inconvenience."

i understand why they are purposefully vague but i need to know so i can tell clients what to do in order to use my theme!

anyone know what it takes?

Comment: `purposefully vague` / `i need to know` The latter defeats the purpose of the former. Only Tumblr would know the exact answer to this.

Comment: i think it's possible someone has figured this out seeing as i'm sure it's a common issue

Comment: Try making 10 posts, even if they are just dummy/holding content. I had an email back from Tumblr about this.